# C# generic method to affect specific object variable

Tags: c#, variables, generics

I want to create a generic method that affects the variable of the object that has been passed, I really only want to send its address and generically affect it. How do I achieve something like this:

```
public class SomeObject() {
   float value1;
   float value2;
   float value3;
}
```

And in another class:

```
void Method1() {

   SomeObject obj;

   if(true) {
     Method2(obj.value1);
   }

   if(false) {
     Method2(obj.value2);
   }

}

void Method2(float value) {
   value++;
}
```

Where "value" in the second method is either obj.value1 or obj.value2 depending on the if-statement. I am sure that this question has been answered before but I don't know how to phrase my question correctly, sorry about this.

Comment: That would be ridiculously hard with generics: there is no way to define generic restriction to have `operator ++`, getting ++ to actually modify property/field of an object is hard, picking unknown fields is hard and not really what generics are for (since it is not clear what generic restrictions you can live with). Some more realistic sample (that at least does something unlike your `Method2` may help along with what type of other objects you want to support with generic version of this method.

Comment: Is `SomeObject.value1` as field or a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to [pass by reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx), like this:

```
void Method1() {

   SomeObject obj;

   if(true) {
     Method2(ref obj.value1);
   }

   if(false) {
     Method2(ref obj.value2);
   }

}

void Method2(ref float value) {
   value++;
}
```

From the definition of `SomeObject` in the question, I am assuming that `value1`, `value2`, and `value3` are fields.

Comment: As long as you don't use generics and use fields instead of properties... Not sure how this answers "create a generic method".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I think that OP does not mean [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). I think he means generic as "not specific/ can be used for many things".

Comment: @YacoubMassad Now that you mention it, I tend to agree. OP must clarify if he is talking about <T> generics or the generic generics.

Comment: This was the answer to my question, I should of been more clear with my definition of generic but it seemed to come across anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for a generic method can be satisfied through the Expressions framework:

```
private void Increment<T, V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> f, T instance)
{
    Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(
        Expression.Assign(f.Body, Expression.Increment(f.Body)), 
        f.Parameters[0])
    .Compile()(instance);
}
```

To increment `SomeObject.value1`, you could call:

```
Increment(a=>a.value1, SomeObject);
```

This method works for both fields and properties of any type that supports the increment operator.  However, note that this method requires dynamic compilation each time it is invoked, and is likely to be much slower than a solution that uses reference parameters.

More generally, one can write:

```
private void Set<T, V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> f, Func<V, V> map, T instance)
{
    V newvalue = map(f.Compile()(instance));
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(V));
    Expression.Lambda<Action<T, V>>(
        Expression.Assign(f.Body, pe), 
        f.Parameters[0],
        pe)
    .Compile()(instance, newvalue);
}
```

Which permits arbitrary assignment based on the current value:

```
Set(a=> a.value1, v=>v+1, SomeObject); // SomeObject.value1++;
Set(a => a.value1, v=>v*6, SomeObject); // SomeObject.value1 *= 6
Set(a => a.value2, v=>90, SomeObject); // SomeObject.value2 = 90
```